# Adding physics property to mesh doesn't do anything?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I have an existing animation via "how to use blender" tutorial from Blender Guru (Donut 3.0). I'm trying to now go beyond and do my own thing but I can't seem to figure out why I can't get any other meshes to move when adding physics to it.

Example, donut already has animation and it spins. I've added a new `Plane` mesh, then for the modifier I added a `subdivision` left it on `simple` with a `levels viewport: 4`. Then I added a `cloth physics` with default settings, hit space bar and it moves maybe a couple centimeters and then that's it.

If I create a new file and try the same steps for the physics it works no problem, so I'm unsure why it won't in my donut file.

All suggestions are greatly appreciated! Please see link below for blend file if you'd like to have a look.

Blender version: 3.0.0, windows 10.

[.Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r278drhb3ntgsqy/donut-3pt0_collision-cloth_v1.blend?dl=0)

Comment: I suspect something here has to do with reading something wrong between versions.  What version of Blender did you start the file?  What version are you using now?  In 3.0, disable subdivision on Icing to see the physics.  Of course, that's crazy, the Icing has no physics, and subdivision shouldn't affect anything, but there it is.

Comment: @Nathan woah! you're right it finally worked. thank you! I actually started all of this in 3.0 brand new install and everything. Very interesting, thank you! Can you please post as answer? everything works now, I set collision on the donut itself and the cloth wraps around it

Comment: Well, the fix doesn't make any damn sense, so in my mind it's not really an answer to the question "Why?"  I'm afraid I don't know why that's the case, it just is.

Comment: ah I see okay well thank you anyhow @Nathan you did still resolve my issue so I can keep moving forward haha so I appreciate it